# Jumping from the point with coordinate 0 to the right, to find a constant minimum jump length to avoid all elements in a given array

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

You are given an array of integers representing coordinates of obstacles situated on a straight line.

Assume that you are jumping from the point with coordinate 0 to the right. You are allowed only to make jumps of the same length represented by some integer.

Find the minimal length of the jump enough to avoid all the obstacles.

Example

For inputArray = [5, 3, 6, 7, 9], the output should be
solution(inputArray) = 4.

[Check out the image below for better understanding:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Lty.png)

I don't understand how the answer for the below test case is 6. Can someone please explain?

inputArray: [1000, 999]

Expected Output:
6

Comment: Well you start at 0. If your jump is size 2 you will end at 2,4,6 (multiples of 2). If your jump is size 3 you will end in multiples of 3 (3,6,9...) So given the numbers 999 and 1000 which is the minimum number that is not a divisor of any of this 2 numbers? 1000 can be divided by 2, 4 and 5. 999 can be divided by 3. Neither can be divided by 6. So answer is 6

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, thanks for explaining, think I understood what is required.

Answer (score 0):

Simple search from 1 up to the size of the largest obstacle:

```py
def solution(obstacles: list[int]) -> int:
    size = max(obstacles)
    for step in range(1, size + 1):
        landings = range(0, size + 1, step)

        if not any(obs in landings for obs in obstacles):
            return step
    return step + 1


assert solution([5, 3, 6, 7, 9]) == 4
assert solution([999, 1000]) == 6
```